# How many different sized holes must be drilled?

Tags: word-problem

A 'starry sky' that's installed on the roof is made with light fibers in a way, that the roof is surfaced with tiles that have been drilled with a proper number of fitting holes. The light fibers are installed into the holes before attaching the tiles.

Mike has been requested to make a starry sky roof, that uses a total of 200 light fibers. The work must be executed so that the roof has 3 different-sized 'stars' drilled into it by these rules:
-20% of the stars must be large, fitting 5 fibers each.
-35% of the stars must be medium, fitting 3 fibers each.
-Rest of the stars are small, each having 1 fiber fit into them.

a)How many holes must Mike drill in total?
b)How many holes are large, medium and small, respectively?

This one has been giving me a headache since I first encountered it. I'd appreciate to hear the reasoning behing the solution.

Comment: If you can work out part b) first then the number of holes needed is the number of large stars plus the number of medium plus the number of small. How far have you got already?

Answer (score 1):

First we need to know the minimum number of stars.
$$HCF(20\%,35\%,45\%)=5\%$$
Now,
$$\frac{100\%}{5\%}=20$$
We need atleast $20$ stars to get an integral answer. For $20$ stars, we require a total of $(20\%\times20)\times5+(35\%\times20)\times3+(45\%\times20)\times1=50$ fibres.

Since we must use a total of $200$ fibres, we need to have $4$ times the number of stars and fibres. So we need a total of $80$ stars.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of stars we're looking for.

$.20*x*5+.35*x*3+.45*x*1=200$

$x+1.05x+.45x=200$

$2.5x=200$

$x=80$